# Automaticaly rename new buffer in term-mode

Tags: emacs

In Emacs, let's create a buffer in [term-mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Term-Mode.html) with `M-x term`. The resulting buffer is named `*terminal*`. If one wants to create another buffer also in term-mode, one usually does `M-x term` again. However, this simply gets back to the first buffer.
Therefore, one has to (1) rename the first buffer with `M-x rename-uniquely`, this buffer now being named `*terminal*<2>`, and (2) create the second buffer with `M-x term`, that buffer being named `*terminal*`.

Would there be a way instead to create another buffer in term-mode without renaming the first ones, so that the new buffer is automatically named `*terminal<i+1>*` where `i` is the number of already-existing buffers in term-mode?

ps: I started reading the [introduction](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/index.html) to programming in Emacs Lisp, in order to write in my .emacs my own function overloading `M-x term`, but I feel like any help will be much needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example with multi-term

```
(defun my-run-term ()
    (interactive)
    (require 'multi-term)
    (command-execute 'multi-term)
    (setq-default truncate-lines nil)
    (if (not (boundp 'term-number))
        (defvar term-number 1 "term index in the current emacs session") )
    (rename-buffer (concat "Term " (int-to-string term-number)))
    (setq term-number (+ 1 term-number)))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-t") 'my-run-term) ;; mappe sur C-T
```